# Query to select rows in sqlite database which are between today's date and 7 days time

Tags: android, sqlite

```js
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    static class LayoutHandler{
        TextView id,subject, assignment, dueDate, notes;

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        LayoutHandler layoutHandler;

        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_listview,parent,false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.id  =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.TEXTid);
            layoutHandler.subject = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textSubject);
            layoutHandler.assignment = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textAssignment);
            layoutHandler.dueDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textDueDate);
            layoutHandler.notes = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.notesTextField);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            row.setTag(layoutHandler);

        }
        else{
            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler)row.getTag();
           notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider)this.getItem(position);
        layoutHandler.id.setText(dataProvider.getAssignmentValue());
        layoutHandler.subject.setText(dataProvider.getSubject());
        layoutHandler.assignment.setText(dataProvider.getAssignment());
        layoutHandler.dueDate.setText(dataProvider.getDueDate());
        layoutHandler.notes.setText(dataProvider.getNotes());
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        return row;
    }
}
```

```js
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listView;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    DbHelper dbHelper;
    ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//
        dbHelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());//
        sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();//
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);
        listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_layout_listview);
        listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
        
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getUpcomingAssignment(sqLiteDatabase);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                final String module, assignment, dueDate, weighting, notes, thisid;
                thisid = cursor.getString(0);
                module = cursor.getString(1);
                assignment = cursor.getString(3);
                dueDate = cursor.getString(4);
                weighting = cursor.getString(2);
                notes = cursor.getString(5);
                DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(weighting, module, assignment, dueDate, notes, thisid);
                listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
}
```

```js
06-27 15:42:39.118    2988-2988/com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905 I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-27 15:42:39.384    2988-2988/com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905 E/Database Operations﹕ Database opened/created from constructor.
06-27 15:42:39.386    2988-2988/com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-27 15:42:39.387    2988-2988/com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905, PID: 2988
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905/com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
            at com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905.DbHelper.getUpcomingAssignment(DbHelper.java:186)
            at com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I have created a small application to track university assignments. Using sqlite database the user can store information such as the assignment name, when it is due and notes on the assignment. I have created a listview which will show upcoming assignments, so any assignments which is due in the next 7 days. I cant seem to get the query right, anyone that could help?? Thanks

```
//My DbHelper class
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String ASSIGNMENT_ID  = "_id";
public static final String ASSIGNMENT_VALUE = "assignment_value";
public static final String SUBJECT = "subject";
public static final String ASSIGNMENT_TITLE = "assignment_title";
public static final String DUE_DATE = "due_date";
public static final String NOTES_ASSIGNMENT = "notes";
public static final String TABLE_NAME_ASSIGNMENT = "assignment_information";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "assignment_info.db";

private static final String ADD_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "+
        TABLE_NAME_ASSIGNMENT+"("+
        ASSIGNMENT_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
        SUBJECT+" TEXT,"+
        ASSIGNMENT_VALUE+" INTEGER,"+
        ASSIGNMENT_TITLE+" TEXT,"+
        DUE_DATE+" DATETIME,"+
        NOTES_ASSIGNMENT+" TEXT);";

    //My query (so far) to return a cursor with the selected assignments
    public Cursor getUpcomingAssignment(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){

    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String today = sdf.format(gc.getTime());

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_ASSIGNMENT + " WHERE "+ DUE_DATE + " >= date('now', '+7 days')";

    Cursor mycursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);
    return mycursor;
}
```

```js
06-27 15:23:54.187  27174-27174/com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-27 15:23:54.188  27174-27174/com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905, PID: 27174
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905/com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905.DbHelper.getUpcomingAssignment(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905.DbHelper.getUpcomingAssignment(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)' on a null object reference
            at com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Remove `+` sign and it's working fine in my case.

Comment: + sign before the 7? If so its still causing it to crash I'm afraid

Comment: Yes. also post your logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//My query to return a cursor with the selected assignments
public Cursor getUpcomingAssignment(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_ASSIGNMENT + " WHERE "+ DUE_DATE + " <= date('now','+7 days') AND date('now')";

    Cursor mycursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);

    Log.e("Database Operations","Method getUpComingAssignment called ");

    return mycursor;

}
```

Got it!

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT:* I see a number of problems with your adapter:

- Okay, now I see what the `DataProvider` is doing.  I'm not a fan of that pattern, but I'll bet your compiler is whining because you have

`public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {`

instead of

`public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<?> {`

or even

`public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {`

- `ArrayAdapter` already has its own internal list, so you don't need to have your own `List` field or even override any of those methods except `getView()`, even the constructor.  You might as well extend `BaseAdapter` if you're going to have all those methods.  I recommend taking out the `List` definition, the constructor and all the overrides except for `getView()`.
- You are calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `getView()`.  `notifyDataSetChanged()` is meant to be called only when the list actually changes.  For example, it is called in the `super.add()` method, which is probably enough to trigger refreshes for your `ListView`.  But it is accomplishing nothing inside `getView()` and you should take it out.

Start with those changes and post your results.  If your `DataProvider` class doesn't have any bugs, you should be in a lot better shape.

---

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor com.ulsteruniversity.eamonn.diary1905.DbHelper.getUpcomingAssignment(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)' on a null object reference`

The problem is not your method, the problem is that you have not initialized the `DBHelper` instance that runs the method.

Comment: This had cleared this problem thanks for that! unfortunately there is an additional problem shown by the new logcat message above?

Comment: Now your problem is that your argument to `getUpcomingAssignment()`, `sqLiteDatabase` is not being initialized.  So far, all your problems have been in `onCreate()`, maybe you should post the code for your `MainActivity`.

Comment: Thanks for the input I have also now added the Main Activity code

Comment: Okay - so you added this line `sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();//` Did that fix your last crash?

Comment: Yes Kris it did, I have also changed the data type to DATE for the DUE_DATE which now stops the errors and the application can run. Although the data is still not being displayed, seems like the getUpcomingAssignment method is not working correctly?

Comment: In which case, now it's time to look at your `ListDataAdapter` code.

Comment: Added the listadapter code, dont think there is a problem with this, as I have created a similar listview in another part of the app and it works fine?